# Calculate TikZ coordinate with Koma's BCOR

Tags: tikz-pgf, koma-script

I use the KOMA scrreprt document class and I specify a BCOR. Now I want to draw with a TikZ overlay, which respects the BCOR.

My command to get the BCOR setting is the following. Maybe that can be improved?

```
\newcommand{\myBCOR}{\makeatletter\the\ta@bcor\makeatother}
```

Anyways, now I want to draw 1cm from the page border **plus BCOR**.
I tried:

```
\draw[semithick,rounded corners=0.5cm]
      ($(current page.north west) + ( 1cm,-1cm) + (\myBCOR,0)$) --
      ($(current page.north east) + (-1cm,-1cm)$) --
      ($(current page.south east) + (-1cm, 1.5cm)$);
```

However, this gives the error `Missing number, treated as zero.`
I found nothing on how to integrate commands into coordinate calculations.

Comment: `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` should enclose the `\newcommand` definition, so they should be moved outside.

Comment: Also, when you have a problem related to an error, it's always necessary to include a minimal example that shows it. We cannot know what is going on without seeing the code that generates the problem.

Comment: Ok fixed your suggestions

Comment: Actually, @Alennano fixed my problem. Moving them outside made it work. :)

Comment: your code is now working?

Comment: Code is now working. I updated the example to show the use of `\myBCOR`. Am I supposed to do anything to mark this solved?

Comment: You can accept the answer below. But you should keep your example the way it was, otherwise the question makes no sense since it's now "correct". :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` should enclose the whole `\newcommand` definition, so you should write it this way:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myBCOR}{\the\ta@bcor}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not change the `BCOR` inside the document it may be better to use

```
\newcommand\myBCOR{10cm}
\KOMAoptions{BCOR=\myBCOR}
```

Note that `\ta@bcor` is an undocument internal length. So its name can be changed in the future.